# How to compute the transition matrix of this channel?

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory, coding-theory

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $X, Z$ be independent RVs with values in $\mathcal{X} = \{0, 1, \ldots , n − 1\}$
>   and with probability distributions $p_X$ and $p_Z$ respectively. Let $Y$ be the RV
>   $Y = X + Z \pmod n$ with values in $\mathcal{Y} = \mathcal{X}$ . Let $C = (X , P, Y)$ be a memoryless channel with input RV $X$, output RV $Y$ and transition matrix $P$.
>
> Show how we can compute P.

**My Attempt:** Let's first assume w.l.o.g that $Z$ takes a fixed value $z \in \{0, \ldots n-1\}$.  By the definition of $Y$ as $Y = X + Z \pmod n$ we see that to have $Y = y$ for $y \in \{0, \ldots, n-1\}$ the RV $X$ has to assume the value $x = y-z \pmod n$. By the independence of $X$ and $Z$ we therefore have

$$p(y \mid  x) = p(X = y-z \pmod n \mid Z = z) = p(X = y-z \pmod n) \cdot p(Z = z).$$

With this we have found an alternate expression for the entries of the transition matrix $P$, but I do not see how I could write it down concretely. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution of $Y$ is a convolution of those of $X$ and $Z.$

Since $$P_Y[Y=y]=\sum_{x} P_X[X=x]P_Z[y-x]$$ so that for example
$$P_Y[Y=0]=\sum_{x} P_X[X=x]P_Z[-x]$$ and
$$P_Y[Y=1]=\sum_{x} P_X[X=x]P_Z[1-x]$$ we can write the transition matrix $P$ of the channel as a circulant $n\times n$ matrix with first row $$[P_Z[0],P_Z[n-1],\ldots,P_Z[1]],$$ and the next row a right cyclic shift of the first row, etc.